# Web Api routing to action with string paramater

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

It seems simple like in ASP.NET MVC but I can't figure out how to map an URI with a string parameter to an action on my controller. So I have three actions in my controller as below:

```
 //GET: api/Societe
    public IEnumerable<Societe> GetSociete()
    {
        List<Societe> listeSociete = Librairie.Societes.getAllSociete();
        return listeSociete.ToList();                        
    }


    //GET: api/Societe/id
    [ResponseType(typeof(Societe))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetSociete(int id)
    {
        Societe societeRecherchee = Librairie.Societes.getSociete(id);
        if (societeRecherchee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            return Ok(societeRecherchee);
        }
    }


    public IHttpActionResult GetSocieteByLibelle(string name)
    {
        Societe societeRecherchee = new Societe();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            societeRecherchee = Librairie.Societes.getSocieteByLibelle(name);
            if (societeRecherchee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
        }
        return Ok(societeRecherchee);
    }
```

So I would like to map an URI with the action:

> GetSocieteByLibelle(string name)

My route configuration is the default one for Wep API project. May someone explain me how to map an URI to that action ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the two routes are resulting in the same method call being invoked.  Try putting a [Route] attribute on one of them as follows:

```
[Route("api/Societe/libelle/{name}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetSocieteByLibelle(string name)
{

}
```

Note that the default /api/Societe/{id} should still hit your first Action.